# How can we prepare GitLab runners using Ansible deploys

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

**Given**

We run an in-house `GitLab` server, with many `projects` (aka "`repositories`")

We provision all servers using `Ansible` (and deploy projects using `pip`)

We deploy to

- dev.project.example.com
- test.project.example..com
- beta.project.example..com
- (and eventually to) www.project.example..com

**When**

We add `.gitlab-ci-.yml` to all `project`s' `repository` roots

We want to use `dev.project.example.com` as a runner for that `GitLab project`

**Then**

What Ansible playbooks could we write to provision `dev.project.example.com` as a `GitLab Runner` for that `project`?

Answer (score 1):

A gitlab runner is a process that f.e. tests, compiles your project, pushes the artefact to you artefact store etc.

A Gitlab runner can be tagged inside Gitlab or via config.toml - so - you can assign runners via tags to Gitlab projects (shared).

Gitlab runner are not designed to run an application 24x7. So - you assign a project to a runner (or a tag or all) to build you application). If you want to deploy the project, use the K8S deployment inside Gitlab (that must be connected to a specific Kubernetes environment based on you Git-branches etc). Or (just an example) run an AWX task that is able to push your new artefact via the artefact storage (docker registry). Also you could just call a SSH remote command on a script (via Gitlab runner) to start a deployment - but don't use the runner to "host" your environment. They will stop (per default after 1h) without a return code.